# Printing variable alongside string iteral with input() function

Tags: python, io

I want to ask a question to the user that includes an already input word in python. How to do it?

```
live = input("Where do you live?")
print("You live in ", live,".")

place = input("Where is", live,"?")
print("Oh! so it's in", place, ".")
```

I have already tried entering the variable and saving it separately. But, it gives error of arguments entered in raw input.

```
TypeError: raw_input() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `format()`:-

```
live = input("Where do you live?")
print("You live in ", live,".")

place = input("Where is {} ?".format(live))
print("Oh! so it's in", place, ".")
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put variable in `raw_input()` or `input()`.

So here you cannot join `live` with `input("x",live,"y")`

You have to write only one statement.

So it will be like this..

`live = input("Where do you live?")`

`print("You live in ", live,".")`

`place = input("Where is it?")`

`print("Oh! so it's in", place, ".")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
live = input("Where do you live?")
print("You live in ", live,".")
print("\n Where is ", live)
place = input()
print("Oh! so it's in", place, ".")
```

Sample run

```
Where do you live?los angeles
You live in  los angeles .
Where is  los angeles
africa
Oh! so it's in africa .
```

Answer (score 0):

1) In `input` method you can't directly use a string and variable together. You have to use them with the help of `format`

```
live = input("Where do you live?")
print("You live in ", live,".")

place = input(f"Where is {live} ?")  # Here f indicates format
print("Oh! so it's in", place, ".")
```

I hope it may help you.